# How to keep the Double(1000) value to be in required currency format?

Tags: android, double, currency, numberformatter

I need to pass a fare amount to the payment gateway. It was working good in English language setting. While I changed the language into Burmese it changes like this **000000၁၀၀၀၀၀**, so I am getting invalid amount.Even I have set currency as Locale.English.But didnt work it.

Your answer is more appreciated!!!

```
 try {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            return nf.parse(s).doubleValue();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0.0;
        }
```

Comment: That code parses the string into a number. You need to show the opposite, the code that produces the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
//calling of method
String your_amount= setCurrencyFormat(your_string);



private String setCurrencyFormat(String amt) {


        if (amt.equals("null") || amt.equals("")) {
            amt = "0";
        }

        double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt);


        //here i have done it for Indian currency i.e "in" you can opt for other countries currency

        Format formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
        return formatter.format(amount);


    }
```

**Note:** I get my amount in string format you can covert you amt to string if it is in integer format

Comment: what issue is happening

Comment: As per your code I am getting (Rupee symbol 1,000.00).But I am expecting 1000 even in all language.